# Prevent IOS notification menu from sliding down

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

On the iPhone and iPad, when you slide your finger down from the top of the screen, the notification menu comes down with the time and your past notifications. Is there a way to keep this from happening when my app is in the foreground? Is there an Xcode setting that I can activate for my app, or a line of code I can put in my viewController? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Implement your own panFromEdge gesture and do nothing in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an instance property called `preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures` which can be overridden. This will not disable the notification center, but it will force the user to swipe twice – the first time, a small tab will extend from the top of the screen instead.  Add the following code to your view controller:

```
override var preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures: UIRectEdge {
    return .top  //Or, return .all to "disable" the control center as well
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get your first excerpt of code working for me, although the preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures worked perfectly thanks!